# SSIS data flow task shows yellow when all child transformations show green

Tags: ssis

I have a foreach loop container, containing a data flow task which flows into an execute sql task.

When I run my package, all transformations in the data flow task eventually turn green - there are some errors due to bad input data, but these are all redirected to various output files.

However, when I go to Control Flow. My Data Flow task is yellow. The Execute sql task is not executed.

There are no errors in Execution Results.

What's going on?

Comment: Yellow means that it is currently in execution. Are you sure the task is just not long to complete?

Comment: The data flow task is completing I'm sure. All the sub-blocks go green. Would a block turn green without completing?

Comment: No it won't. All sub elements being green is no indicator that the data flow is finished. It may be hanging while in the `COMMIT` phase of the transaction. Is the data wrote to your destination?

Comment: Yep, all data is written to the db / error files.

Comment: Sometime it happens in the debugger that a component stay yellow but the following get executed. If the component is yellow and the next component is not executed, there is definitely something hanging.